# Согласование глагола с местоимением

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые, местоимения

Вопрос относительно согласования глагола с местоимением (множественное или единственное число). Как правильно?
Денис и Ольга посмотрите документацию, а **я** с Александром посчита**ем**...
Денис и Ольга посмотрите документацию, а **я** с Александром посчит**аю**...
Денис и Ольга посмотрите документацию, а **мы** с Александром посчита**ем**...

Answer (score 2):

1. *Я с Александром; мы с Александром* — при таких оборотах (именительный падеж + предлог **с** + творительный падеж) сказуемое может стоять как в форме множественного, так и в форме единственного числа.

Академическая «Русская грамматика» отмечает, что «если в группу со значением совместности входит местоимение 1-го (*я, мы*) или 2-го (*ты, вы*) лица, то глагол в сказуемом, уподобляясь числовому значению местоимения, имеет ту же личную форму, что и это местоимение:
***Я** с отцом (с сестрами) **пойду**; **Мы** с отцом (с сестрами) **пойдем**;

**Ты** с матерью (с сестрами) **останешься**; **Вы** с матерью (с сестрами) **останетесь**».*

[Согласование сказуемого с сочетаниями типа «брат с сестрой»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo)

2. *Денис и Ольга* — это обращение, его необходимо отделить запятой.

**Денис и Ольга, посмотрите документацию, а я с Александром посчитаю...**
(Подлежащим является только местоимение в именительном падеже ["я"], а существительное в творительном падеже выступает в роли дополнения, обозначая лицо, сопутствующее производителю действия.)

**Денис и Ольга, посмотрите документацию, а мы с Александром посчитаем...**
(В роли подлежащего выступает все сочетание ["мы с Александром"], т. е. действие приписывается двум взаимосвязанным равноправным субъектам.)

***Ты** с Олей **будешь** в одной комнате пока что, а твою комнату Бобику* (А. П. Чехов. Три сестры).
*— А во-вторых, — не обращая внимания на слова подруги, сказала Леся, — **мы** с тетей **собрались** на теплоходе кататься* (Д. Калинина).